# Regex expression to update the div's style properties - width & height

Tags: c#, regex

Sample string:-

```
<div class="ui-droppable" id="ParentDIV" style="width: 286pt; height: 212pt; background-color: #00752d; background-image: none;">
    <div class="be-canvas-grid" style="background-image: none">
        <div style="width: 200px; height: 50px; top: 77px; left: 162px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); overflow: hidden;" data-uid="2" class="be-component be-text  ui-draggable ui-droppable">
            <span>hello from simple text</span>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 161.567px; height: 39.5667px; top: 127px; left: 172px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; color: rgb(201, 87, 201); overflow: hidden;" data-uid="3" class="be-component be-text  ui-draggable ui-droppable">
            <span>{[C-FULLNAME:LC]}</span>
        </div>
        <div style="width: auto; height: auto; top: 196px; left: 216px;" data-uid="4" class="be-component be-image  ui-draggable">
            <img src="https://localhost/a/images/BarcodeType1.jpeg" data-qrstub="" alt="">
        </div>
        <div style="width: 200px; height: 50px; top: 6px; left: 12px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; color: rgb(201, 87, 201); overflow: hidden;" data-uid="5" class="be-component be-text  ui-draggable ui-droppable">
            <span>asd</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to pull the `ParentDIV` elements's style properties i.e. width and height. Then I want to update the width and height css properties with my values. The order of height and width properties in the style tag of `ParentDIV` may get changed also.

Please suggest the regex. I would be making this code changes in C#.net.

Regex expression can build with the help of online tool http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse html. This has been said a million times. Read this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: i don't have an option but to parse it with regex..

Comment: I have to manipulate the html in server-side action based on some other action. There has been already many regex manipulations  happening in the string..

Comment: Sounds like bad code and not an excuse. Save yourself a world of hurt and use a parser.